# Firebase initial code

Tags: javascript, firebase

Where do I put the firebase initial code that is responsable to give the keys? Before the html tag closes? or before the body tag closes?

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "jsdfiojsifjsiodfjiosfiosdfsj",
    authDomain: "dribbbleapi.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://dribbbleapi.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "dribbbleapi",
    storageBucket: "dribbbleapi.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "931058019229"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it before the `body` tag closes like this:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>

...

<!-- Import and initialize the Firebase SDK -->
<script src="/__/firebase/3.7.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/3.7.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script>
  // The Firebase SDK is ready to rock!
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange(function(user) { /* … */ });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So inside a `script` tag then close `body` and close `html` tag